# Regular expression to check for cookies with no name

Tags: regex, cookies

I want to create an IIS rewrite rule that runs for any request where there is a cookie with no name (as Classic ASP can't handle these).

I need a regular expression that looks for an equals sign either at the beginning of the cookie string or after a semi colon, and possibly with white space (space, tab, line feed, carriage return, etc) before it.

(; or beginning)(optional white space)=

I'm crap at regular expressions but here's my proposed one:

```
^|;\s*=
```

Is this right, or how would this best be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there, just put `^|;\s*` inside a group, so that the `|` OR applies to the both.

```
(^|;)\s*=
```

Comment: Should that be `(^|;)\s*=` as the whitespace could be after either beginning or semi colon?

Comment: ya, exactly. I thought space may exists after semicolon only.